# Drag UIKeyboard to hide

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikeyboard

I wonder how to prepare similar functionality to Skype app, which allow user down drag UITableVIew to hide in live mode UIKeyboard.
Do you have any suggestions to resolve this issue, or maybe have used before of some cocopods?

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 7, this functionality has been built into the [UIScrollView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/keyboardDismissMode)

Choose whichever of these fits your needs best.

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

If however you want to achieve this in an older iOS version, you can't do anything interactive, but you can use the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` to dismiss the keyboard when the user starts scrolling.